# Python: How to overcome invalid argument of incorrect file path

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a Python script that captures a screenshot everytime the left mouse button is pressed. I am using this guide as a reference: https://pytutorial.com/python-capture-screenshot-mouse-clicked

My problem is coming from the file path. I am wanting the screenshots to be saved in the "Screenshoots" folder, but am instead getting the error, `"OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:/Users/tjdob/codebase/Screenshoots//26-10-2022_22:12:52.jpg'"`

My base directory is `C:\Users\tjdob\codebase`

Here is the code I am attempting to run:

```
from pymouse import PyMouseEvent
import pyautogui
import os


class ScreenshotsTaker(PyMouseEvent):

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path # path to save Screenshot
        PyMouseEvent.__init__(self)

    def click(self, x, y, button, press):
        # if button number 1
        if button == 1:
            # if button number 1 is pressed (clicked)
            if press:
                # Take ScreenShot
                myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
                # Save ScreenShot file
                now = datetime.now()
                # Date Time Now
                dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
                # Save ScreenShot
                myScreenshot.save(os.path.join(self.path,dt_string + ".jpg"))
                # Output:
                print("ScreenShot is taken")


C = ScreenshotsTaker(path="C:/Users/tjdob/codebase/Screenshoots//")
C.run()
```

I am sure it is a simple fix. Any direction would be appreciated

I have tried changing the filepath, and switching backslashes with forward slashe.

Comment: The tutorial is on unix, and you are trying it on Windows. Did you try changing the path to this: `C:\Users\tjdob\codebase\Screenshoots\`?

Comment: You've got to use Windows paths.  Or better yet, use something like pathlib which makes it OS agnostic.

Comment: Windows filenames can't have `:` in them.

Comment: Also you have 2 forward '/' s in the path along with what @sj95126 mentioned

Comment: @ThisaruG When I change the path to: (path='Users\tjdob\codebase\Screenshoots') I get the same error with the message, OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Users\tjdob\\codebase\\Screenshoots\\27-10-2022_00:29:07.jpg'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the filename you're creating using `strftime()`:

```
26-10-2022_22:12:52.jpg
```

Windows filenames can't have a `:` in them, because `:` in a file path is the separator between a drive letter (e.g. `C:`) and a path. There is an exception to this to use a `:` as part of a feature called Alternative Data Streams, but that's not what you're trying to do here.

Because it's not a valid filepath, you get the `Invalid argument` error.

You'll have to format the timestamp portion of the filename differently - possible alternative format options are:

```
%H-%M-%S   ->   22-12-52
%H.%M-%S   ->   22.12.52
%H%M%S     ->   221252
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. I modified the strftime() as you suggested and my function now works as intended. Thanks again!

Comment: @TysonDoberneck: Glad it helped. If you're happy with the answer, you may want to click the checkmark next to it to accept it, so that the question will show as resolved.